# QGIS Server: Activate the WMTS Capabilities & WMS Extent using pyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-server, wmts

I am on the last step of creating a WMS Project using pyQGIS.
I would like to access the WMTS Capabilities and select all the existing layers as long as using the current canvas Extent for the coordinates of the project to be published. I have not find any documentation about the name of the objects.

```
# 8. Project Properties: QGIS Server
# -------------------------------------------------------------
# Activate the Service Capabilities
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WMSServiceCapabilities" , "/", True)

# Insert a Short Name
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WMSServiceTitle" , "/" , project_name)

# Insert a Title
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WMSRootName" , "/" , project_name)

# Insert the Organization
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WMSContactOrganization", "/" ,"abc")


# *Edited: WMS Capabilities: Advertised extent:Check -- Using 
# etrimaille's solution
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
e = iface.mapCanvas().extent()
e.xMaximum()
e.yMaximum()
e.xMinimum()
e.yMinimum()

QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WMSExtent" , "/", [str(e.xMaximum()), str(e.yMaximum()), str(e.xMinimum()), str(e.yMinimum())])

# *Edited: WMTS Capabilities: Publish the Project and the Layers. 
#The Project's boxes (published, PNG, JPEG are now checked) 
#I do not know how to access the Layers though and check the boxes
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WMTSLayers" , "Project", True)
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WMTSPngLayers" , "Project", True)
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WMTSJpegLayers" , "Project", True)
```

[image: WMS Extent][image: WMTS Capabilities]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save a list :

```
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WMSExtent" , "/", [min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. I hope I can find the WMTS Capabilities too!

Answer (score 2):

With the help of this code https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/9a0a1297c2e585cdbc3dbeeb64f5792024a451f9/src/app/qgsprojectproperties.cpp#L1479
and many attempts I found out how to to check the boxes of the WMTS Capabilities:

```
vectorLayers = [layer.id() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer)]

# WMTS Capabilities: Publish the Project and the Layers
# ---Project-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WMTSLayers" , "Project", True)
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WMTSPngLayers" , "Project", True)
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WMTSJpegLayers" , "Project", True)

# ---Layers-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WMTSLayers" , "Layer", vectorLayers)
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WMTSPngLayers" , "Layer", vectorLayers)
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WMTSJpegLayers" , "Layer", vectorLayers)

QgsProject.instance().write()
```

With this addition the solution to my problem is complete and question is closed.