# Set/Get Value of QGIS-Server Variables in ProjectSettings

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3, qgis-server

I want to automatically read and write settings of my QGIS-project with Pyqgis. Especially i want to do this for the QGIS Server Service Properties (Top of QGIS-Server Tab).

I found this [Link](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/settings.html) but i cant solve my problem with it...

I also found this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428508/qgis-server-activate-the-wmts-capabilities-wms-extent-using-pyqgis), but i want more Variables and i cant find the names of them. Someone have a full list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a very simple solution:

The variables are stored in the Project-File and i can see them, if its stored as .qgs.
I will copy and paste them and set the variables with the following syntax:

```
settings = {
    'WMSServiceCapabilities': True,
    'WMSRootName': 'Testproject',
    'WMSServiceTitle': 'Tesproject',
    'WMSContactOrganization': 'Its me'
}

for setting in settings:
    QgsProject.instance().writeEntry(setting , "/" , settings[setting])
```